# Java 5 - Bring Modal Dialog to Front on any click

Tags: java, swing, focus, modal-dialog, jdialog

Setting: Java 5 - no upgrade possible.

I have a large application that has a number of modal dialog windows.  I have heard that hidden modal dialogs can result in uninformed users going so far as to restart their computer.  Even if a user knows how to ALT-TAB (in MS Windows, at least), it's a pain.  From what I understand, this was in part fixed in later versions of Java, but that's not an option here, unfortunately.

So, is there any way to force a modal dialog to be shown if any part of the running application is clicked on?  I was thinking it might have something to do with either MouseListeners, GlassPanes, or something else.  However, I've got a bunch of other stuff I'm supposed to be working on, so I don't have a lot of time to devote to hashing this out right now. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks so much!

Comment: what type on Modality, 1) `setModal(true)` 2) `ModalityType(some from API)` but fo real help you have to post http://sscce.org/, because (maybe I wrong) I don't know another Focus issues in Java5 or Java6

Comment: `setModal(true)`.  ModalityType is not in Java5 (only 6 and later)

Comment: If no one knows where I can start looking for a solution, I'll post an SSCCE tomorrow...gotta run off and do work now...

Comment: right you are added into Java6, then this method can't solve your issue, are you tried - what's happens, when you add/remove/change `setModal(true)` dynamically, set that to required JDialog, that would be easiest and simple way

Comment: SSCCE - create JFrame with two JDialogs that manage two JButtons

Comment: I'll work on an sscce, but it's a bit difficult to model the problem...I've got classes that contains a JTable inside a JPanel inside a JTabbedPane inside a JFrame.  lol

Comment: maybe you have issue with Concurency in Swing, because you can manage empty JDialogs without any issue, but you had problem with Container that loading data, then probably you'll the same problems in Java6 :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, is there any way to force a modal dialog to be shown if any part of the running application is clicked on?

When you create the dialog you need to specify the parent frame as the owner of the dialog. Then whenever you click on the frame any dialog that is a child will also be shown.

Comment: Unfortunately the dialog requires a Frame or Dialog parent, which in the context of the problem, is not available.  The dialog is being shown by a class containing a JPanel, which is added to a JTabbedPane, which is then put into a JFrame...

Comment: Unless there's a way to find the top frame of a JComponent, but I don't know of a way to do that...

Comment: see: SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...).